# Нужно найти сумму объема товаров (м3)

Tags: javascript

Собственно нужно найти общий объем товара в корзине. (размеры у товаров разные, допусти 24х33х57 и тд)

```
var inCart = _.find(data.order_lines, function (product) {
   let array = product.dimensions.split('x');  //разбил массив на цифры.
   let arrayRed = array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator * currentValue); // объем каждого товара
                });
```

Как теперь сложить все полученные числа? Застрял на этом. :/

Comment: дайте пример входных данных

Comment: Если правильно понял: есть массив с товарами (у них разные размеры, dimensions: "48x24x35", dimensions: "55x28x43" и тд)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let products = ["1x1x1","2x2x2","3x3x3"];
let sum = products
    .map(
        (product) => product.split("x") // разбиваем строку на массив
            .reduce((a,b) => a * b) // находим объем
    ).reduce((a,b) => a + b) // суммируем получениы объемы

console.log(sum); // 36 (1 + 8 + 27)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное :)